# dissapear div onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html

```
<input type="text" id="match1">
<div id="divf">It is a div which has a dark future</div>
<button>Not Remove</button>
```

and script

```
$(function(){
    $("input").blur(function()
    {
       $("#divf").remove(); 
    });
});
```

Now as it is clear from code i want the div to be removed on blur on input .But i don't want div to be removed if someone is clicking on button .I have no idea how to do it.Can somebody solve this problem

Comment: Bluring is bluring, whether you leave the input because you finished typing or you leave it to click on the button ... what are you trying to do? maybe you should consider other approach. If it's validation error handling there are better mechanism you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put on just text field having id match1 then div will be removed only when the field has blue

```
$(function(){

   var isButtonClicked = false;
   $('button').one('click', function(){
      isButtonClicked = true;
   });

    $("#match1").blur(function()
    {
       if(!isButtonClicked)
            $("#divf").remove(); 
    });
});
```

If you want to put on just type text then the div will be removed on blue of every text box

```
    $(function(){
       var isButtonClicked = false;
       $('button').one('click', function(){
      isButtonClicked = true;
    });

    $("input[type=text]").blur(function()
        {
           if(!isButtonClicked) 
               $("#divf").remove(); 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You could set a timeout in the `.blur()` and then clear it when the button is clicked.

```
var to = false;

$('input').blur(function() {
    // start the timer
    to = setTimeout('removeDiv', 200);
});

$('button').click(function() {
    // if the timer is still running, clear it
    to && clearTimeout(to);
});

function removeDiv()
{
    $("#divf").remove();
    // reset timer
    to = false;
}
```

When the focus goes from the input straight to the button (it's clicked), the timer is cleared and the div is not removed.

Comment: I think, this looks promising. I would add the onfocus handler as well on the button, so keyboard navigation can work

Comment: I would handle it with a timeout as well!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead of your code

```
$(function(){
    $("#match1").blur(function()
    {
       $("#divf").remove(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Oops he has deleted the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have editted @Adil answer and got what i wanted

```
$(function(){
       var isButtonClicked = false;
       $('button').one('mousedown', function(){
      isButtonClicked = true;
    });

    $("input[type=text]").blur(function()
        {
           if(!isButtonClicked) 
               $("#divf").remove();
               else isButtonClicked = false;
        });
    });
```